# PostgreSQL Connection is closed

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jhipster

I am trying to make a simple Spring Boot application generated with jHipster to get from a postgresql a list of users from a postreSQL database and display it using a rest controller, but when i run it i get

```
Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
```

this is my application-dev.yml

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
        include: swagger
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    jackson:
        serialization.indent_output: true
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/loginApp
        username: postgres
        password: admin
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        show-sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory
    mail:
        host: localhost
        port: 25
        username:
        password:
    messages:
        cache-seconds: 1
    thymeleaf:
        cache: false

liquibase:
    contexts: dev

jhipster:
    http:
        version: V_1_1 # To use HTTP/2 you will need SSL support (see above the "server.ssl" configuration)
    cache: # Cache configuration
        ehcache: # Ehcache configuration
            time-to-live-seconds: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour in the cache
            max-entries: 100 # Number of objects in each cache entry
    # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile, so BrowserSync can access the API
    cors:
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: "*"
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers: "Authorization"
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                secret: my-secret-token-to-change-in-production
                # Token is valid 24 hours
                token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
                token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
    mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
        from: loginApp@localhost
        base-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
    metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
        jmx.enabled: true
        graphite: # Use the "graphite" Maven profile to have the Graphite dependencies
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 2003
            prefix: loginApp
        prometheus: # Use the "prometheus" Maven profile to have the Prometheus dependencies
            enabled: false
            endpoint: /prometheusMetrics
        logs: # Reports Dropwizard metrics in the logs
            enabled: false
            report-frequency: 60 # in seconds
    logging:
        logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 5000
            queue-size: 512
application:
```

This is my dbUser.service.ts file

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Response, Headers, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {DbUser} from "./dbUser";
import {BaseService} from "../base/base.service";

@Injectable()
export class DbUserService extends BaseService{
    allUsersUrl = "http://localhost:8080/user/allDbUsers";
    userUrl = "http://localhost:8080/user/dbUser";

    constructor(private http:Http) {
        super();
    }

    getAllUsers() : Observable<DbUser[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.allUsersUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    createUser(): Observable<DbUser>{
        let cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders });
        return this.http.post(this.userUrl, DbUser, options)
            .map(success => success.status)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getArticleById(dbUserId: string): Observable<DbUser> {
        let cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let cpParams = new URLSearchParams();
        cpParams.set('id', dbUserId);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders, params: cpParams });
        return this.http.get(this.userUrl, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

I dont think that the angular 4 side of the application is the problem. I may be wrong about this, but i have verified it and i dont see any problem.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you actually read the exception? It originates from LiquiBase during startup of your application.

Comment: that liquibase is auto generated by jhipster. i did not modify a single word there

Comment: Please add the rest of the stack trace from your error.  It should contain the reason why Liquibase could not start